# Передача данных между формами

Tags: 1с

Добрый день.

Только начал разбираться с 1С программированием и столкнулся с проблемой.

**1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.13.219) нетиповая конфигурация**

Есть справочник контрагентов. У каждого контрагента есть связанные с ним события.
Открываем форму выбранного контрагента, в этой форме есть кнопка "добавить документы", при нажатии на которую выскакивает форма выбора документов, в которой можно выбрать "Событие". Выбираем событие, открывается форма создания события.

Вопрос: как передать данные (например самого контрагента) в форму события из открытой формы выбранного контрагента?
Или как мне сослаться на конкретную форму? чтобы, находясь в самой форме события, взять все, что мне надо, из формы контрагента.

Что должно получиться: из формы контрагента вызываем форму события, и в поля ввода формы события сразу подставляется значения, взятые из формы контрагента.

[свойства кнопки добавления](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=638d7a81f7f283b3172feceae7b85eca)

[нажимаем кнопку](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=de64fb0d74c570083c4c476b33651a58), открывается окно выбора документа, в котором выбираем событие, после чего отрывается форма события

Comment: Здесь нужно уточнить версию платформы и типовая или нет конфигурация

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В модуле документа "Событие" должна быть процедура **ОбработкаЗаполнения(Основание)**. Система автоматически вызывает эту процедуру и передает в нее параметром "Основание" данные объекта "по ссылке", который явился инициатором заполнения. В вашем случае это контрагент.

Вот тут вам и нужно посмотреть, какой тип имеет основание, если это **справочникСсылка.Контрагенты** тогда заполняете, если нет продолжаете по умолчанию.

Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
Если ТипЗнч(Основание) = Тип("СправочникСсылка.Контрагенты") тогда
    <Заполняем какие то реквизиты>
    <При необходимости выходим из процедуры методом Возврат;>
КонецЕсли;
```

Comment: Спасибо! В изначальном коде "ОбработкаЗаполнения" вызывалась вручную из модуля формы, и в качестве параметра туда ничего не передавалось, и это вводило меня в ступор - я не знал, что эта обработка может автоматически вызываться с готовыми параметрами :)

Comment: в версии 8.1 эта процедура вызывалась только автоматически при создании объекта "вводом на основании", а вот в 8.2 она вызывается всегда, т.е. при любом создании объекта. Поэтому всегда в начале этой процедуры необходимо выполнять проверку параметра "Основание" на неопределенность или соответсвие ссылке конкретного типа.
Я сам при переходе на 8.2 несколько раз наступал на эти грабли :)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете событие ОткрытьФорму(<ИмяФормы>, <Параметры>, <Владелец>, <Уникальность>, <Окно>), то в параметры записываете Структуру

```
Структура = Новый Структура("Контрагент", Контрагент)
```

Далее при создании формы события проверяете существует ли свойство "Контрагент" в параметрах(метод структуры "свойство"), если да, то заполняете необходимый реквизит.
Надеюсь, я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: Я не знаю, где посмотреть код открытия этих форм, он не описан ни в модуле объекта ни в модуле формы контрагента. А к кнопке добавить привязан стандартный обработчик "Добавить". Скриншоты выложил в вопросе.